# Why Does Pyomo Behavior Change When Passing parameters to constraint function?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

This code works correctly.

```
def m(model, i):
    return model.fd_amt[i] <= getattr(model, 'br_sa_ind')[i] * global_m

setattr(model, ind+"_m",Constraint(model.br_standalone_I, rule=m))
```

But this

```
def m(model, i, ind_name):
    return model.fd_amt[i] <= getattr(model, ind_name)[i] * global_m

setattr(model, ind+"_m",Constraint(rule=m(model,model.model.br_standalone_I, 'br_sa_ind') ))
```

results in this error:

> ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue
>   object
>       fd_amt[br_standalone_I]
>           (expression: fd_amt[br_standalone_I]  <=  13 *
>           br_sa_ind[br_standalone_I]) ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint br_sa_ind_m:
>       ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object
>       fd_amt[br_standalone_I] ERROR: Constructing component 'br_sa_ind_m' from data=None failed: ValueError:
>       No value for uninitialized NumericValue object fd_amt[br_standalone_I]

Is there a reason Pyomo constraints behave this way with explicit parameters?

Comment: To specify a constraint, you need to specify the rule with a reference, not with a function call (see last line of your code). However, to pass a parameter to this constraint, I can't think of any ellegant way. Looking at your code, I'd say that maybe you should look into your sets. Maybe 'br_sa_ind' could be the only element in your set that you use to build the constraint. But I'd rather wait to see if there is a right answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior by replacing `rule=` with `expr=`:

```
setattr(model, ind+"_m",Constraint(model.br_standalone_I))
for i in model.br_standalone_I:
    getattr(model, ind+"_m")[i].set_value(expr=m(model, i, 'br_sa_ind'))
```

The purpose of `rule` is so that indexed constraint expressions can be constructed using a common rule. If you have a singleton constraint, you can specify the expression using `expr`.

Comment: This did allow me to pass in the vars correctly. Note to future users: if you're using 'expr' you will also need to write an iterator instead of letting 'rule' do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you use a function call `rule=m(...)` instead of a function reference `rule=m`.

While this solution may not answer to your problem directly, it may offer a workarround. I still don't know if Pyomo allows what you are asking (passing a parameter to a rule).

Create a new set with your parameter that you want to pass as your only element. You could add more elements later if you want, if you handle your parameters in your rule's function adequately. For simplicity, let's begin with only one element.

```
model.S = Set(initialize=['br_sa_ind'])
```

Then use this set as your parameter to your rule. It's like using a for all notation, with only one element. (For all element in set S and in set br_standalone_I, apply rule m). You should create your constraint using

```
Constraint(model.br_standalone_I, model.S, rule=m)
```

So your entire code would look like

```
def m(model, i, ind_name):
    return model.fd_amt[i] <= getattr(model, ind_name)[i] * global_m

setattr(model, ind+"_m",Constraint(model.br_standalone_I, model.S, rule=m))
```

This is not entirely elegant, but it should work. I yet want to hear if you can specify parameters to a rule while creating a constraint.

Comment: So just to clarify, if there is more than one variable name in the Set that is passed to the third argument, it will cycle through each of them?

Comment: In short, yes. Giving the sets as parameters to create a new Constraint component makes Pyomo cycle through all elements of those sets, creating in fact one constraint per combination of elements in the sets. It's the equivalent of saying "for all elements in set S".

Comment: But be careful, as this is more like a hack. I don't know how this will scale  itself with future parts of your code. Normally, sets in constraint should be used to provide indices to your variables or parameters in your constraint rule.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I should be able to instead pass a list of indeces to one indicator var instead of passing in a list of indicator vars to keep this scaleable. Appreciate the feedback.