# How to Pass External Data to Pyomo Constraint Rule

Tags: pandas, constraints, rules, pyomo

The classic way to build a constraint or list of constraints in Pyomo is to use a rule

E.g.

```
def ConSatisfyDemand(model,p):

    return sum(model.OutQty[pl,r] for (pl,r) in model.OutputTypeIndex if pl==p) == DemandQty[p]
```

However, if DemandQty is external data e.g. a Pandas series, it needs to be passed to the function somehow or declared as global to be in scope. There doesn't seem to be any handy way to to do the former as per [Why Does Pyomo Behavior Change When Passing parameters to constraint function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109887/why-does-pyomo-behavior-change-when-passing-parameters-to-constraint-function)

A global declaration is ok in a script but inadvisable in a production application.

An alternative is to loading DemandQty data up as a parameter to the model in order to have access to it. But this may not scale performance wise and can be awkward to maintain a second copy of the data just for Pyomo.  Is there a way to access this 'external data' within a constraint rule function?

Comment: If you are concerned by the global access to 'DemandQty', why don't you just make it a parameter of the model, which could be easily initialized from a pandas series?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I've done as a workaround, see above. But as the data gets quite big.  Pyomo docs advise that direct data access is preferable.  Situation just seems funny as examples abound of using external data in constraint rule functions but no-one has mentioned scoping probs Maybe most work is being done in open code i.e. scripts.

Comment: can you provide a pointer to the dox section that promotes "direct access"?  In my understanding, this is direct access as the data is held in the model object and there shouldn't be any concern about size here...even for large models.

Comment: I can't! I don't know where I saw that.  I have amended my question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to nest the constraint inside another function:

```
from pyomo.environ import (ConcreteModel, Constraint, Var, Set)

m = ConcreteModel()
m.v = Var()

cities = ['Chicago', 'Dallas']
m.cities = Set(initialize = cities)
DemandQty = {'Chicago': 20, 'Dallas': 40}  # External dict, could be pandas object

def nested_rule(m, external_obj):
    
    def demand_rule(m, city):
        return m.v == external_obj[city]
    m.nested_con = Constraint(m.cities, rule=demand_rule)
    
    return 

nested_rule(m, DemandQty)
```

In this way, the `DemandQty` is still accessible by the constraint, but only within the  `nested_rule`. This may also be advantageous if you want to write more than one `Constraint` that will require access to the external data.

Note: here, `m.cities` is a set that is initialized inside the model. Otherwise `cities` would also need to be passed to `nested_rule`.